# Nginx Regex issue with rewrites

Tags: regex, nginx, webserver

I'm trying to rewrite urls like these:

> https://staging.sciencehook.com/featured/five-things-you-may-have-missed-over-the-weekend-76?amp

to these:

> https://staging.sciencehook.com/featured/five-things-you-may-have-missed-over-the-weekend-76/amp

This is my rewrite snippet:

```
rewrite ^(.*)\?amp$ $uri/amp last;
```

Now, this snippet is not really doing any rewrites. Please let me know the problem here.

Thanks!

Comment: `rewrite` (and `location`) uses a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which does not include the query string. Use a `map` and/or `if` statement instead.